# PysideのQProgressDialogを、別スレッドで実行させたいです。

Tags: python

表題の通り、QProgressDialogを別スレッドで実行したいのですが、安定せずに困っています。
サードパーティ製の重い処理を実行させつつ、ダイアログが固まらないようにしたいです。
やりたいことは、基本は次のようなスクリプトです。
(サードパーティ製モジュールの入る部分はコメントアウトしてあります)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import time
# import third_party_module


def start_third_party_module():
    item_num = 3

    d=QtGui.QProgressDialog()
    d.setRange(0, item_num)
    d.show()

    for i in range(item_num):
        # ここに、重い処理が入る
        # third_party_module.do(i)
        d.setValue(i)
        print i
        time.sleep(2)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        button.setText("Click me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.pushBtn)

    def pushBtn(self):
        start_third_party_module()

def main():
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow(qApp)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())

main()
```

上記スクリプトを実行させると、一応ダイアログは表示されますがcancelボタンが押せないなど都合が悪いです。 
サードパーティ製のモジュールをQThreadで実行することも試してみたのですが安定せず(頻繁に落ちる)、メインの中でサードパーティ製のモジュールを実行させつつ、プログレスダイアログにも触れるようにしたいと思っております。

どうかお力添えをお願いいたします。

追記：上記スクリプトが、前回は端折りすぎていたので、情報を追記しました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コード例では見当たりませんが、`main`で`QApplication.exec()`を実行している、という状況であっていますか?

Comment: @user20098 さん
すみません。スクリプトの情報を端折り過ぎていたため、追記しました。
mainWindowからボタンを押すと、処理が走ります。

Comment: @user20098 さん ご回答ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

重い処理のせいではなく、`QProgressDialog`の表示方法の問題と思います。
具体的には、`MainWindow.pushBtn`以降で一連の処理をさせているのが原因と思います。

2か所変更すると、`QProgressDialog`の表示更新と操作が可能になると思います。(重い処理をさせつつ)

1. `button`のconnect方法。
   以下のように変更する。

   ```
       # 変更前
       button.clicked.connect(self.pushBtn)
       # 変更後
       button.clicked.connect(self.pushBtn, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
   ```
2. `dialog`の表示方法。
   `pushBtn`以降の処理で表示させるのではなく、その外で表示させるようにする。
   具体的には、`QProgressDialog`オブジェクトを`MainWindow`のメンバとし、`button.clicked`にconnectして表示させるようにする。

   ```
       # 変更後(MainWindow.__init__内)
       self.dialog = QProgressDialog()
       button.clicked.connect(dialog.show)
   ```

原因は、`button.clicked`のイベントで一連の処理(`MainWindow.pushBtn`以降の処理)を行っているため、イベントディスパッチャに処理が戻らないためです。(戻らないと他のイベントが処理されない)
ですので、`button.clicked`のイベントをイベントキューに入れるようの動作させるために前者の変更を行います。
同様に`QtGui.QProgressDialog`でイベントディスパッチできるよう、後者の変更を行います。

＃connectの第2引数については、[`Qt.ConnectionType`のドキュメント](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/Qt.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.Qt.ConnectionType)を参照ください。

Comment: @user20098さん ご回答ありがとうございます！
ただ、私の理解不足で(connectの第2引数や、イベントディスパッチャの概要は理解したのですが)、ここからどう組んでいけばいいのかが分からずにいます。。(申し訳ないです。。)
お時間があるときに見ていただけると幸いですmm

Answer (score 1):

スクリプトをできるだけシンプルにし、@user20098さんの処理も加えてみました。
QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnectionがどのように作用するのかも確認したのですが、
ここからどう組めば良いのかがわからなく。。
(下記スクリプトでは、QProgressDialogが白く固まった状態で表示され、
MainWindow.pushBtnの処理後にプログレスバーやキャンセルボタンが表示される)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import time

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        button.setText("Click me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.pushBtn, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

        self.dialog = QtGui.QProgressDialog()
        button.clicked.connect(self.dialog.show)

    def pushBtn(self):    
        for i in range(3):
            print i
            time.sleep(2)


def main():
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow(qApp)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())

main()
```

QThreadの処理と組み合わせるようにしていくのでしょうか?
私の理解不足で申し訳ないのですが、よろしくお願いいたします。m(_ _)m

Comment: `MainWindow.pushBtn`内で`self.dialog.setRange(0, 3)`と`self.dialog.setValue(i)`を呼び出すと画面更新されませんでしたか?

Comment: お世話になっております。画面は表示(更新)されたのですが、cancelボタンと右上の×ボタンが直ぐに反応しないようです。
可能ならばそれらのボタンも反応させたいと思っております。(Pysideは1.2.0を使用しております。バージョンにより反応が違う場合もあるのでしょうか?)

Answer (score 1):

`pushBtn()`内のforループ内で、`QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()`を呼び出すようにすると、もう少しレスポンスが改善すると思います。

```
    # コード例
    # MainWindowのコンストラクタでQApplicationのオブジェクトを
    # 引数に取っているので、それをself.aとして格納している前提とします。
    def pushBtn(self):
        for i in range(3):
            print i
            a.processEvents()
            time.sleep(2)
```

＊

この場合でも、「`time.sleep(2)`」の箇所で実行する(と予想する)「重い処理」中は操作に対するレスポンスは得られないと思うので、そうであれば、「重い処理」を`QThread`で切り離すことになると思います。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。
やはり、ダイアログと処理でスレッドを分ける必要があるんですね。
今回は、サードパーティ製のモジュールがスレッドを分けると動作不安定になるという特殊な事情がありますので、processEventsで対処しようと思います。
ありがとうございました。